# The difference between "sum" of vector space and "union" of set theory: two problems

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does the main difference between "sum" and "union" lie in the definition, where the "sum" extends the space further through linear combinations, unlike the "union" in a set?

I encountered this problem in *Linear Algebra Done Right - 4th edition*, Exercise 2C, 19:
Explain why you ***might guess***, motivated by analogy with the formula for the number of elements in the union of three finite sets, that if $ V_1, V_2, V_3 $ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dim (V_1 + V_2 + V_3) &= \dim V_1 + \dim V_2 + \dim V_3 \\
                        &- \dim(V_1 \cap V_2) - \dim(V_2 \cap V_3) - \dim(V_1 \cap V_3) \\
                        &+ \dim(V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3)
\end{aligned}
$$

Initially, I thought I could prove it; my mistake was assuming $\dim(V_3 \cap (V_1 + V_2)) = \dim((V_3 \cap V_1) + (V_3 \cap V_2)) $, which **does not hold** due to the properties of the sum. Am I understanding this correctly now?

In addition, I'm still unclear with exe.20: Prove that if $ V_1, V_2, V_3 $ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dim(V_1 + V_2 + V_3) &= \dim V_1 + \dim V_2 + \dim V_3 \\
                      &- \frac{\dim(V_1 \cap V_2) + \dim(V_1 \cap V_3) + \dim(V_2 \cap V_3)}{3} \\
                      &+ \frac{\dim((V_1 + V_2) \cap V_3) + \dim((V_1 + V_3) \cap V_2) + \dim((V_2 + V_3) \cap V_1)}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

How should I solve it with the clarification of the "sum"?

Comment: Indeed, $\dim(V_3 \cap (V_1 + V_2)) = \dim((V_3 \cap V_1) + (V_3 \cap V_2))$ is not true. You can see this by looking at, say, three different one-dimensional subspaces of the plane.

Comment: Start with defining a basis for the 3-way intersection.  Next, use this basis as the subset of the bases of the pairwise interesections.  Finally, use these bases to build a basis for the original vector spaces.  The math falls out from the union on these bases.

Comment: To see why you "might guess" the answer to 19, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle . You can prove 20, but not the way you tried. I think you can deduce 20 from 19.

Comment: One reason you might think this is true is that if all subspaces are of the form $\operatorname{span} S$ for subsets $S$ of some fixed basis $B$, then $\dim \operatorname{span} (U+V) = |U\cup  V|$ and so the identity is true.